# Calling a hook used in multiple places on first render and validator

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am quite new to React. I have a component that renders a form (using Ant Design) that contains a file upload. On the first render of the page I need to make an http call. So I have this code:

```
const [someBooleanState, setSomeBooleanState] = useState<boolean>(false);

useEffect(() => {
    SomeClient.getSomething(someIdFromProps).then((things) => {
        const someBoolean = things.some(
            (things) => things.someProp === 'SOME_VALUE',
        );
        setSomeBooleanState(someBoolean);
    });
}, [someIdFromProps]);
```

Each time a file has been uploaded, changed, or deleted, the validator for the file upload is called that makes the same request as before in useEffect.

```
<Form.Item
    name="upload"
    label="Upload File"
    rules={[
        {
            required: true,
            validator: async () => {
                let someBoolean;
                SomeClient.getSomething(someIdFromProps).then((things) => {
                    someBoolean = things.some(
                        (things) => things.someProp === 'SOME_VALUE',
                    );
                    setSomeBooleanState(someBoolean);
                });
                return someBoolean ? Promise.resolve() : Promise.reject();
            },
            message: 'Please upload a file with certain thing',
        },
    ]}
>...</Form.Item>
```

Now I made a custom hook `useSomethingQuery` which uses the `useQuery` hook to make the request. I tried to use the custom hook in the `useEffect`, but I quickly learned that you can't do that. Same story with the validator. What do I have to do to replace the `SomeClient` calls with the custom hook to make the request and make React happy? That is make the request on first render and then in the validator using the custom hook.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you could do something like this. This way your custom hook makes sure the fetching happens once, until the form sets userFile, in which case the same useEffect triggers again.

```
const component = (orgFile) => {
  const [userFile, setUserFile] = useState();
  const file = useFileQuery(userFile || orgFile);
  
  return (
    <>
      <Upload onUpload={setUserFile} />
    </>
  );
);
```

```
const useFileQuery = (file) => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch
    const result = SomeClient.getSomething(file);

    setResult(validateSomething(result));
  }, [file.id]);

  return result;
};
```

Or using `useQuery`, which triggers the fetching based on a changed `queryKey`.

```
const useFileQuery = (file) => {
  const queryKey = `file-query-${file.id}`;
  const result = useQuery(queryKey, () => SomeClient.getSomething(file));
};
```

Comment: I am not sure if you understood what I am trying to do or what you mean by 'timing'. I just want to replace both SomeClient calls with the custom hook. One custom hook call on first render, and all others in the validator when a file is uploaded/deleted/changed.

Comment: I do not see how this improves your answer, sorry.

Comment: Excuse me, I gave you only half the answer. I edited the post!
(Forgive me, I'm a new contributor, not new to react :D )